# temporal interpolation of artery angiogram images sequences

Tags: python, interpolation

I have many sets of medical image sequences of the artery on the heart. Each set of sequenced medical images shows the position of the artery as the heart pumps. Each set is taken from different views and has different amount of images taken.

I want to do a temporal interpolation based on time (i was told that the time could be represented by the frame number. however i have no idea what the frame number is or what does it refer to. Could you enlighten me please?) I have two options: by interpolating the whole image frame or interpolating artery junction positions (coordinates). How do i go about doing both options?

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine each of the images as a still photo the frame number would be a sequence number that shows what order the images should be displayed in to produce a movie from the stills.  If the images are stored in an array it would be the array index of the individul frame in question.

Comment: I would start with an optical flow transform of the frames to get the deriviatives of the changes in intensity between the frames and then see if you could apply linear interpolation of pixel intensities to estimate the images that might exist between frames.